# How to set the print name using XE C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

My application is able to print its output to a conventional printer using the `TPrinter` class but i need to be able to set the file location in code when printing to pdf (via Wind2PDF). Win32 has a `DOCINFO.lpszOutput`property that can be set to achieve this - is there a way of setting this in C++ Builder with the TPrinter class ? Looking at the documentation / searching didn't provide any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DOCINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183574.aspx) struct is used with the Win32 [`StartDoc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145114.aspx) function, which `TPrinter::BeginDoc()` calls internally.  However, `BeginDoc()` always sets `lpszOutput` to NULL.  So, there is no possibility of specifying an output location with `TPrinter`.  You will have to stop using `TPrinter` and instead use the Win32 API directly, at least when printing to Wind2PDF.